# How to build automatically different JARs from same code using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, inheritance, ant

I have many more classes in the project but for now please consider only A, B and C classes.

```
abstract public class A {...}

public class B extends A {...}

public class C extends A {...}
```

Then later I have a code, say in class D, like this

```
A a = new B();
//A a = new C();

//use a's methods
```

**So my question now is how to easily configure in Eclipse building of two separate JARs.** First one should have `B.class` included and `C.class` excluded and code as `A a = new B();` The second one should have `C.class` included and `B.class` excluded and code as `A a = new C();`

I do not know many things about Ant and Maven. Do I need to use them in this case?

Maybe, something wrong with my design, if so, please let me know.

Comment: I would say you will need an `ant` task.

Comment: @SJuan76, how about the code `A a = new B/C();` ?

Comment: I did overlook that. I would say that you should use CDI for that, but that would mean changes in your program.

Comment: @SJuan76, isn't this case is common? You are welcome to post an answer about CDI usage. It is ambigious, by the way.

Comment: CDI is a complex subject with many options. To make it simple&dirty, put in a .properties file the name of the class you want to use (`ant` can do that), to instantiate the class you read the file and use reflection to create an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to is mainly a code loading problem, not an Ant problem.

Just the two statements you presented for creating a new class instance:

```
A a = new B(); 
A a = new C();
```

The constructors are called using static code. Ant can not change the code, therefore the only way with Ant I see is generating a Factory class with Ant as part of the build process, depending if `A` or `C` is included into the JAR

But that would result in a project that can no longer be used directly in Eclipse as the original source code in the Eclipse project misses the factor class.

A IMHO better approach is dynamic class loading (may be combined with reflection). You can automatically search for classes that extend `A` or you add a configuration file/info to the JAR specifying which class to create (e.g. properties file).
Place the properties file in the src folder with the Java file and load it via `this.getClass().getResource("myclass.config");`

The config file can contain the class name that should used for creating a new instance.
The following code snipped assumes that `B` and `C` both have a public constructor that does not take any argument:

```
String classNameToLoad = ... // loaded from config file example "mypackage.B"
final Class<?> c = Class.forName(classNameToLoad);
final Class<? extends A> ac = c.asSubclass(A.class);
final Constructor<? extends A> a_ctor =  ac.getConstructor();
final A a = a_ctor.newInstance();
```

Comment: Is it possible to use same code for Eclipse and Jar, if I follow approach with dynamic class loading?

Comment: Yes, as the code itself decides based on a configuration file which class to load this will work also in Eclipse. Only configuration in MANIFEST.MF will not work as the class files are not in a JAR file. See also my updated answer.

Comment: I am very poor in dynamic class loading and reflection. Can you elaborate more in the answer with more code or instruction, or related materials, so I would accept your answer since it the best so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your eclipse you if you right click your project, you will have an option `Export`
Click on that, and select jar, then name the jar, select the classes you want in it.
Repeat this for the other jar.

check this [http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-33.htm)

Comment: I want to do it automatically. And I use Export - Executable Jar in there there is no choice for classes.

Comment: did you see your, project, unwrap that, by selecting a '+' in the left hand side, and then go to your build path, and select your classes

Comment: please check the reference of the steps

Comment: There are two options 'Jar' and `Executable Jar` in Eclipse Export. I use the second one and there you cannot select classes. Also it would be very tedious to do it manually all the time

Comment: If you need it automatically, you will need ANT, for it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to have 3 separate Java projects in Eclipse.  Based on your example, that would be

- B code project
- C code project
- A common code

Eclipse allows you to reference the bin directory of another project from your project in the build path.

Then you can export (or use Ant) the B and C projects as separate projects.